# ImportError when importing from another module

Tags: python

My app structure is the following:

```
./mod1/__init__.py
./mod1/utils.py

./mod2/__init__.py
./mod2/test.py
```

Now in ./mod2/test.py I do:

```
from mod1 import utils
```

But I get an ImportError that no module is named `utils`. What's wrong?!

Comment: What directory are you in when you run the code? And how are you invoking the code? Both matter, because they affect how `sys.path` is set up by Python. Ignore advice to hack `sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH` manually -- it's usually not needed for normal work on a typical project.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, the parent directory of `mod1` and `mod2` must be in `sys.path`, which probably means that it needs to be in the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. Please see [the module search path documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

One solution that does not require modification of `PYTHONPATH` is to place your executable script in the parent directory of `mod1` and `mod2`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a top-level folder in the sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path_to_app_folder')
```

You should write this line before `from mod1 import utils`. Also add `__init__.py`:

```
./mod1/__init__.py
./mod1/utils.py

./mod2/__init__.py
./mod2/test.py
__init__.py
```

You can dynamically get the path to the app folder from `./mod2/test.py`, using  os.path.abspath. So, you code for  `./mod2/test.py` will look like this:

```
import os
import sys

top_level_folder = os.path.abspath('../')
sys.path.append(top_level_folder)

from mod1 import utils
```

Comment: where to write these lines? and is 'path_to_app_folder' is the path to './' ?

Comment: also I don't want to hardcode the path to the app folder, can you please give me a concreate example how to dynamically get the path to the app folder?